# MySQL 8.0.21 stopped working

Tags: 20.04, mysql

[image: terminal_output]

I had installed MySQL successfully but then after some days it stopped working so, I removed and then reinstalled it, but unfortunately, it's not working. I tried restarting the service but it gives the same error.when i searched for error log there isn't one!

edit:added more terminal output

[image: systemstl output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`systemctl status mysql` says that the MySQL system database was not found. Did you delete it?

In any case you will need to recreate the database as it says using `mysqld --initialize`

Comment: ive added the systemctl output and there is no error log file

Comment: @deva the proper way to view the log is sudo cat /var/log/mysql/error.log

Comment: i used nano text editor, it works just fine

Comment: @deva what's inside the log? is it empty?

Comment: yes it doesn't exist